# Read and Step into .Net Framework Source Code with VS 2005

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005

I did ask whether this was possible in VS 2008 which was answered in [Is it possible to Read and Step into .NET Framework Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296840/read-and-step-into-net-framework-source-code).

However my problem is that I am using 2005 and not 2008.

Does anyone know whether this is possible please??

The reason I want to do this is to better understand C# paradigms.
With Java this is possible and I learnt a tremendous amount by being able to read code written by engineers

Comment: Ask yourself the question: do I really need to step into .NET Framework source code?...

Comment: ...what is the actual problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes should be able to.

If you [download](http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=9646) the beta version of .NET Reflector 6 it has a Visual Studio plugin that allows you to do step-through-debugging on assemblies that you don't have the source code to.

I read on a [blog](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/bart/archive/2009/03/23/72559.aspx) that they were going to support VS 2005, although I've never tired myself...